# Xcode11 application loader

Tags: ios, xcode11, application-loader

After upgrading xcode11, I found that the application loader was canceled. Now how to upload the ipa package to the appstore, is there an alternative application loader tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple has released a new util tool called Transporter that basically does what application loader used to do.

You can find it here: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12

Comment: Yes, transporter can replace application loader, thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use Xcode's Top Menu -> Window -> Organizer -> Archives Section -> find the archive you want to upload -> Distribute App from the right pane.

Comment: The actual situation is like this. I have not installed the release certificate on my own computer. This method is not suitable for me. I don't need my computer archive. I can only get the ipa package here. I only upload it. Ipa package

Comment: Then there is an alternative option. You can use "xcrun altool --upload-app -f your_ipa_file -u $username -p $password" from terminal

Answer (score 1):

Apple removed Application Loader from XCode 11. You have to:

1. Open the Organizer window in Xcode (menu Window > Organizer)
2. Click on the Archives icon in the top middle
3. Select the desired archive by app name and date
4. Distribute

If you use Visual Studio 2019: To create Archive you have to right mouse click on iOS project and choose Archive...